Issues enabling HTTPS on Nginx with Let's Encrypt for a Strapi API and React app
I'm trying to enable HTTPS on my Nginx server for two applications: a Strapi API and a React client application.
React running from /home/rocky/231009twins/front/dist on port 50001 with pm2. Served on www.myappdomain.com/.
Strapi running from /home/rocky/231009twins/back/build on port 50002 with pm2. Served on www.myappdomain.com/back.
HOW CAN I SETUP THE SSL FOR THE DOMAIN SERVING FROM THE FOLDERS THE APPS ARE USING?
I have configured Nginx as follows:
NGINX:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myappdomain.com www.myappdomain.com;

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /home/rocky/231009twins/front/dist;
        allow all;
    }
  
    location = /back {
        return 301 /back/admin;
    }

    location /back {
        rewrite ^/back/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:50001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:50002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

I have tried using Let's Encrypt to obtain the certificates, but I have not been able to complete the validation challenges.
LetsEncrypt setup try:
$ sudo certbot certonly -v
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

How would you like to authenticate with the ACME CA?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: Runs an HTTP server locally which serves the necessary validation files under
the /.well-known/acme-challenge/ request path. Suitable if there is no HTTP
server already running. HTTP challenge only (wildcards not supported).
(standalone)
2: Saves the necessary validation files to a .well-known/acme-challenge/
directory within the nominated webroot path. A seperate HTTP server must be
running and serving files from the webroot path. HTTP challenge only (wildcards
not supported). (webroot)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): 2
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Please enter the domain name(s) you would like on your certificate (comma and/or
space separated) (Enter 'c' to cancel): myappdomain.com www.myappdomain.com
Requesting a certificate for myappdomain.com and www.myappdomain.com
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for myappdomain.com
http-01 challenge for www.myappdomain.com
Input the webroot for myappdomain.com: (Enter 'c' to cancel): /home/rocky/231009twins/front/dist

Select the webroot for www.myappdomain.com:
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: Enter a new webroot
2: /home/rocky/231009twins/front/dist
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): 2
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain myappdomain.com
Challenge failed for domain www.myappdomain.com
http-01 challenge for myappdomain.com
http-01 challenge for www.myappdomain.com

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: myappdomain.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 162.19.246.107: Invalid response from http://myappdomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ALOh-9VKunkQi-DUMvQAWTFFpFs3VCjXqfYAJGZuOmw: 403

  Domain: www.myappdomain.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 162.19.246.107: Invalid response from http://www.myappdomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/BCUWytiU7d7wXxCyXPAQmAYXVKKv60X8uzbZTKpcerw: 403

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files created there can be downloaded from the internet.

Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.

nginx error log
2024/08/20 02:08:55 [error] 232871#232871: *1 open() "/home/rocky/231009twins/front/dist/.well-known/acme-challenge/WIqdsgkImo5-gWS35bLl98tahZM0GzMaQV-Pw9aQ8-0" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 23.178.112.211, server: myappdomain.com, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/WIqdsgkImo5-gWS35bLl98tahZM0GzMaQV-Pw9aQ8-0 HTTP/1.1", host: "myappdomain.com"
2024/08/20 02:08:55 [error] 232871#232871: *2 open() "/home/rocky/231009twins/front/dist/.well-known/acme-challenge/uQm6CtHPCKGHWLBXanEuzdj_RajV6hubQSS3JdUNgPk" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 23.178.112.215, server: myappdomain.com, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/uQm6CtHPCKGHWLBXanEuzdj_RajV6hubQSS3JdUNgPk HTTP/1.1", host: "www.myappdomain.com"
2024/08/20 15:09:36 [notice] 233877#233877: signal process started
2024/08/20 15:23:26 [error] 233894#233894: *3 open() "/home/rocky/231009twins/front/dist/.well-known/acme-challenge/ALOh-9VKunkQi-DUMvQAWTFFpFs3VCjXqfYAJGZuOmw" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 23.178.112.108, server: myappdomain.com, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/ALOh-9VKunkQi-DUMvQAWTFFpFs3VCjXqfYAJGZuOmw HTTP/1.1", host: "myappdomain.com"
2024/08/20 15:23:26 [error] 233894#233894: *4 open() "/home/rocky/231009twins/front/dist/.well-known/acme-challenge/BCUWytiU7d7wXxCyXPAQmAYXVKKv60X8uzbZTKpcerw" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 23.178.112.100, server: myappdomain.com, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/BCUWytiU7d7wXxCyXPAQmAYXVKKv60X8uzbZTKpcerw HTTP/1.1", host: "www.myappdomain.com"


What have you tried? What commands? What error messages did certbot give you?

@vidarlo I updated it

And error logs/access logs from nginx?

@vidarlo nginx error log updated

see "---webroot-path" near the end of https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/man/certbot.html (but running this from your home directory is a BAD idea)


2024/08/20 02:08:55 [error] 232871#232871: *1 open() "/home/rocky/231009twins/front/dist/.well-known/acme-challenge/WIqdsgkImo5-gWS35bLl98tahZM0GzMaQV-Pw9aQ8-0" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 23.178.112.211, server: myappdomain.com, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/WIqdsgkImo5-gWS35bLl98tahZM0GzMaQV-Pw9aQ8-0 HTTP/1.1", host: "myappdomain.com"

This says it all - nginx doesn't have permissions to open the file.
Remember that to chdir to a directory, the user running nginx needs +x on every directory in the path, e.g. /home/, /home/rocky etc, in addition to read-permission on the file it wants to read.
As a general note, it's probably not a good idea to have a webroot in /home; it has some security implications. A better suggestion would perhaps be /var/www or /srv/.
